# Unable to select a production account ID you want to use to promote your integration key?

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to set my integration key to live and when I am prompted to set the production key, it is greyed out.  My account type is using a basic API plan (not a free plan or a trial).

Would anybody be able to confirm if the basic API plan is sufficient enough for a production environment?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a customer service question and not a programming question.

Comment: @KenWhite I was told directly from their customer service support to ask on stack overflow

Comment: What they told you is irrelevant. This isn't their site. All questions here must adhere to this site's guidelines, and what a specific API plan of theirs allows is not a programming question as defined in this site's guidelines. Their customer service can confirm what is (and is not) included in their basic API plan.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm this. Basic API plan should suffice.
Please read the directions for Go-Live here - https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/go-live and follow the steps carefully. Follow up with DocuSign support if you are unable to complete the process.